# Error when using xarray's built in interp function with dask

Tags: interpolation, dask, python-xarray

I am trying to use xarray's interp function together with the chunk function, which is a dask array feature.

Taking the example under 'Example' at http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/interpolation.html I am able to use the interp function just fine. The simplified code I use to do this is:

```
at = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature').isel(time=0)

x = np.linspace(240, 300, 100)
z = np.linspace(20, 70, 100)
lat = xr.DataArray(z, dims=['z'], coords={'z': z})
lon = xr.DataArray((x[:, np.newaxis]-270)/np.cos(z*np.pi/180)+270,
                    dims=['x', 'z'], coords={'x': x, 'z': z})

dsi = at.interp(lon=lon, lat=lat)
```

The problem arises when I try to combine this interp function with xarray chunk by modifying the above code in the following way:

```
at = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature').isel(time=0)
at = at.chunk({'lat':10})        # added chunking inducing a dask array

x = np.linspace(240, 300, 100)
z = np.linspace(20, 70, 100)
lat = xr.DataArray(z, dims=['z'], coords={'z': z})
lon = xr.DataArray((x[:, np.newaxis]-270)/np.cos(z*np.pi/180)+270,
                    dims=['x', 'z'], coords={'x': x, 'z': z})

dsi = at.interp(lon=lon, lat=lat)
```

The code fails at line

```
dsi = at.interp(lon=lon, lat=lat)
```

The error I get is:

*ValueError: Can't specify drop_axis and new_axis together*

I think what is happening is that the interp function is replacing a coordinate and dask cannot deal with this. Is this a bug that needs fixing within xarray or is there something that I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved. It turns out the problem arrose from using an outdated version of dask (0.13). By updating to dask version 0.24.0 the error above no longer occurs.

See github thread for more clarification:

https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3342